# Extent report test is marked as failed when it's node test has been retried

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I have a test automation project that uses: Java, Maven, TestNG, Selenium WebDriver and Extent Reports (5.0.9 latest).

Most of my tests are using DataProviders and I also have RetryAnalyzer implemented - test/test case is retried once if it has failed.

My Extent Reports "design" looks like this: a method annotated with @Test is represented by `ExtentTest extentTest = extentReports.createTest([...]`. Each case from that method's data provider is represented by a node: `extentNode = extentTest.createNode([...]`.

The result of that structure is this:

[image]

*Sample Test* has a data provider with 3 cases. Each case is represented by a node that is listed on the right. A node can be expanded to see steps, logs etc..

The problem that I am having is with scenario like this: one of the data provider cases fail and is retried. The retry run of that case passes.

After the initial run of a case is failed, `extentTest` status is set to *Fail* automatically because I do `extentNode.fail([...]` on exception in test method. In @AfterMethod method I remove initially failed node from the report: `extentReports.removeTest(extentNode)` but that doesn't change the status of `extentTest` - it's status is still returning *Fail*.

The result of that issue is this:
[image]

*Sample Test* is listed as failed but each node is passed.

I tried `extentTest.pass("description")` - it just adds a passed step to a test but does not change the overall test status.